# SQL email trigger sending query as text as opposed to the actual result

Tags: sql-server

I've created a trigger on a table that send an email, however it sends the query as text as opposed to the actual results of the query.
Hopefully someone can tell me where I'm going wrong. Trigger is:

```
[dbo].[EventMail] ON [dbo].[Table1] AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE Column1 LIKE  '%Test%')
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @msg nvarchar(max)
        SET @msg = 'SELECT * FROM Inserted Where Column1 Like ''%Test%'''
        --// CHANGE THE VALUE FOR @recipients
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
        @recipients=N'email@email.co.uk', 
        @body= @msg,  
        @subject = 'Worksheet Error', 
        @profile_name = 'profilename'
    END
END
```

Comment: because you are sending the query, not its results. you should execute that query and build a string with the results before sending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is in quotes.  Take out the single quotes and it will set @msg to the results of that query.

A warning though.  It will fail if that query returns more than one result.  You should also declare the column.

Comment: Hey Tteeple, thanks for the response. I've tried your suggestion and it's returning the error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Comment: Put the `SELECT` in parentheses like so: `(SELECT * FROM Inserted Where Column1 Like '%Test%')`